# How to use word embeddings for prediction in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

I'm trying to work through the Tensorflow tutorials and have gotten stuck trying to enhance the [RNN/language model tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) so that I can predict the next word in a sentence. The tutorial uses word embeddings as the representation for the words.

Since the model learns on the word embeddings, I'm assuming that any sort of prediction I add will output the same embeddings. What I can't figure out is how to convert from those embeddings back to the word ids from the dataset. The only example I have seen kept an in memory data structure with the reverse of the mapping of wordid -> embedding and used that for lookups. This obviously won't work for all problems. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have both `word_to_idx` and `idx_to_word` from the vocabulary, this is the pseudocode for what you do

Imagine the input for prediction is "this is sample"

```
batch_size = 1
num_steps = 3 # i.e each step for the word in "this is sample"
hidden_size = 1500
vocab_size = 10000
translate the `word_to_idx` for the input `"this is sample"`
get the word embeddings for the each word in the input
Input to model will be word embedding of size 1x1500 at each time step
Output of model at each time step will be of size 1x1500
y_pred is output at last step from model for the given input 
adding projection to output (i.e y_pred x Weights(hidden_size, vocab_size) + bias(vocab_size, )  = 1x10000)
now sample the output through the below function to get the index with max probability
generate idx_to_word from the index we just got
use the generated word along with the previous input to generate next word until you get `<eos>` or some predefined sentence stopping.
```

Here's an example of sampling from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py):

```
def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
    # helper function to sample an index from a probability array
    a = np.log(a) / temperature
    a = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a))
    return np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, a, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand but its going to take a day or two to get around to trying it. I'll mark it as the answer after I can try it.